# How to save an individual page in a Word 2010 document as a separate document?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I would like to save an individual page of a Word 2010 document as a separate document in its own file. I would like to do this without simply copying and pasting into a new document, because the formatting isn't quite right when I do this (even when I try pasting with formatting and other paste options). How do I do this?

Comment: I am facing this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of the whole file, then delete all the other pages by selecting all the text before, pressing delete, then doing the same for the text afterwards.

Comment: doing what you say is messing with the formatting of the page I want to save as a separate document. Is there any other way out?