# Save Pages of a Document as Separate Documents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2007

I am currently using MS-Word 2007 (.docx) format.

I have a Word Document with the following Pages:

- Page 1: Event Details
- Page 2: Event Description
- Page 3: Rules and Regulations
- Page 4: Event Budget

I have spent a considerable amount of time in writing this document with good formatting.
The problem I am facing here is that I have to save each page of the document seperately and then email them as separate attachments.

How do I do that?

What I have tried:

- Copying and Pasting individual pages of the Document into new Word document file - but the formatting is not getting copied properly even after selecting the "Keep Source Formatting" option.
- [How to save an individual page in a Word 2010 document as a separate document?](https://superuser.com/questions/395540/how-to-save-an-individual-page-in-a-word-2010-document-as-a-separate-document) - Answer given for this question has also been tried but the formatting of the pages I am not deleting is getting highly screwed up [Formatting of The Pages that have tables]?

What should I do?

Comment: do you need them to be editable?
otherwise, get a PDF printer and print selective pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is using subdocuments. See the Microsoft help page here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/combine-or-split-subdocuments-HP005186930.aspx

It talks about creating subdocuments under the heading *Split a subdocument into two subdocuments*.

There is a useful Yahoo answers question here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070921100104AAU8Ebh

If you don't need to edit it, you can export to PDF (Don't use a PDF printer, use Word's optional plugin) and *explode* the PDF, using a tool such as [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

Comment: FYI Yahoo Answers shut down this year unfortunately, links to any legacy Yahoos no longer work. Also, the provided link to the Microsoft help page no longer works :(

Comment: Two broken links.

Answer (score 3):

I have a Word Document that I needed to save each page as a individual Document in Rich Text Format. You can change the variables for a .txt file, docx file, etc., as needed, but remember to change the `FileFormat=.`
Note that this starts at the current page you are on `Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowsePage` and continues thru a loop for the next 99 pages (100 total).

You can modify the macro to fit your need.

The variable `i` represents the file number (DCX_1.Rtf) (DCX_2.Rtf) etc.

```
For i = 1 To 100
    Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowsePage
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Copy
    Documents.Add
    Selection.Paste
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\__BOOK\JUNK\"
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="DCX_" & i & ".rtf", FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF
    ActiveDocument.Close
    Application.Browser.Next
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

Click 'Save as' Choose PDF, and click 'options' in the same screen. Under options you can choose which pages to save!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this? I'm not able to see that option in my version of Word.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is firstly copy and paste your document to have two copies. On one copy open it and go to save - as type in event details then on your main document go to the last page, to the last line, last word of the sentence erase all the text in all the pages you dont need by using <kbd>Backspace</kbd>... even if it takes longer it will still keep your formatting.

repeat the above with the rest event description, rules and regulations and event budget.

Comment: I think in the question I have already mentioned that deleting a few pages and kepping the rest doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the Word file as PDF using the "Microsoft Print to PDF" virtual printer.
2. Split the PDF file using [I Love PDF](https://www.ilovepdf.com/split_pdf#split,extract)

Answer (score 0):

### Simplest method: Save four copies and pare each one down to a single page.

I said it all in the title.

For situations where this would be onerous you could get into using macros or the [somewhat dangerous Master Documents methods](https://addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm#PageStart). For four pages, though, you've spent far more time just posting here asking about it than this would take.

Answer (score -2):

Word 2010 actually allows you to copy and paste whatever you like from a Word document while keeping the same format as the original document. After copying the relevent text from the source document, open a new Word Doc, right click, and from the past options click 'Keep Source Formatting'.

Comment: The question is about Word 2007 (1st sentence), and discusses this not working ("What I have tried", 1st bullet).